# Toolchain to crosscompile Applications for BBB

Tags: linux, arm, ubuntu-14.04, beagleboneblack, toolchain

My native machine is ubuntu based 14.04 LTS x86_64 system, I want to cross-compile applications and QT programs for Beaglebone black, which is an armv7 based system running on Debian 2015 distribution.

Which toolchain I should install on my native system, to get this done?

Comment: see if this helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9yFyWsyyGk ... You are probably running linux on beaglebone black so you would have to install   arm-linux-gnueabi* see http://elinux.org/Toolchains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very usefull link how to set up the crosscompiler, uboot, kernel and the filesystem for a beaglebone black.
If you only want to crosscompiler, then just follow the few code lines in the Crosscompiler chapter
https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black

Answer (score -1):

To cross-compile applications you need to use the ' arm-linux-gnueabihf ' compiler in the Ubuntu. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was released with gcc-4.8.2. It is really important that the version of this GCC compiler matches the version deployed on the beaglebone black image. The reason for this is that different compilers have different libc versions, and version mismatching causes linker errors that are very tricky to solve.
You can try running,

```
gcc --version
```

on both your native Ubuntu system and the Beaglebone Black and see if the gcc version matches. If yes, you are good to go. Otherwise, install the appropriate toolchains.