# cross compilation for ARM: error no such file or directory/command not found

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I have written simple Hello world program and compiled it with `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` compiler. It compiles well but when i try to execute it on ARM machine it complains "no such file or directory". I think `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` is for embedded Linux only due to e(mbedded)abi. Is it different from ARM Linux ABI?

Please help me to solve this problem

code is here

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello world !\n");
  return 0;
}
```

compiled as

> arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -o crosscomp hello.c

When i execute this crosscomp on target ARM machine error is crosscomp no such file or dir

**EDIT** When I was using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc the entry point was not matching with the target machine entry point (readelf -l crosscom) but when I compiled with aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc entry point matched with target machine. But now error becomes permission denied on ./crosscomp. I tried with sudo which says crosscomp: no such command.

**Note** I posted same question on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/904685/cross-compilation-for-arm-error-no-such-file-or-directory but got no response.

The output of readelf is as below

ELF Header:

```
 Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           AArch64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x400470
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          4488 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         29
  Section header string table index: 26
```

Comment: what's the output of `ls -l crosscomp` ?

Comment: Ok, in short this error is because the toolchain is not meant for Target ARM processor, you need to use the exact same toolchain which is used to compile the rootfs for target board.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Any suggestion to discover that toolchain

Comment: You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387040/how-to-retrieve-the-gcc-version-used-to-compile-a-given-elf-executable).

From any binary on that target rootfs, maybe busybox. If the comments are not stripped out.

Comment: Refer the vendor website. It should have toolchain or BSP download link.
Can you tell me, where have you got the BSP for this board or how have you compiled the filesystem for it?

Comment: this is for a linux install on some ARM?

Comment: @old_timer yes target is Linux on ARM

Comment: I am starting to think we may also need to know exactly which ARM CPU this is

Comment: @zwol Only info available for CPU is that it is standardized as ARMv8

Comment: There are a _lot_ of different CPUs under that umbrella.  Another thing you could tell us on Monday is the output of `uname -a` and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` executed on the target machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to run a cross-compiled executable on target device fails with: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929092/trying-to-run-a-cross-compiled-executable-on-target-device-fails-with-no-such-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This peculiar error message happens when the *dynamic loader* required by a particular executable is missing.

You can find out the name of the dynamic loader that you need by applying `readelf` to the problem executable.  On my x86-64 Linux box, for example

```
$ readelf -l /bin/ls | grep 'program interpreter'
  [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

("program interpreter" is another name for "dynamic loader".)

So, run the above command on your `crosscomp` binary *on your development box*.  (If you don't have `readelf` or you get error messages, try `arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf`.)  The file named after "program interpreter:" needs to exist *on your target ARM machine*.  If you don't know where to get it, please post the output of the above command + `ls -l` of the directory that should have the missing file in it.

Comment: thanks zwol I have confirmed that entry point and loader are same/accurate for target machine. when I straced crosscomp, second syscall is write with string permission denied despite it is printing command not found. I badly stuck

Comment: @shami Could you please copy and paste the **complete and unedited** strace output into the question?  Also the output of `ls -l ./crosscomp` and the output of `readelf -e ./crosscomp`.

Comment: Thanks I will be able to do this on Monday

Comment: @shami One more thing; it's a silly unlikely problem, but just to make sure, do `chmod +x ./crosscomp` and then try running it again.

Comment: the file flags are -rwxrwxr-x 1 readelf has very long output. how to add that?

Comment: @shami Only the top part is interesting: `readelf -e ./crosscomp | sed '/^$/q'` and edit the output into the question.

Comment: How about the strace output?  Is that what you won't be able to provide till Monday?

Comment: yes if addresses are not important then string passed to write (2nd syscall) was permission denied despite it was printing command not found when executed with sudo

Comment: The thing is, I want to know what the *first* syscall was, in exact detail.

Comment: first call was execve with path to crosscomp. I can post exact detail on Monday

Comment: problem has been solved. There was a silly mistake on my side when I checked file flags of crosscomp I checked these on development machine. When I checked file permissions on target machine, the file was not executable :(. I just executed chmode +x  it started to work :) Thanks for cooperation. My first error was interpreter mismatch, plz change the ls part of your answer to suggest chmod +X. It will help others to find solution quickly.